# String-based ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, user-interface

I'm working on a project in Eclipse, and after googling some resources, I can't find a basic tutorial to achieve what I want to do.

I need to make a list view with simply Strings from an arraylist in it. Nothing fancy - and I'd like to able to slide the items off the screen or press a button to remove them from the list.

Is there a simple way to do this? Please share tutorials if you know any that could help me with this particular problem.

Comment: Do you want to show a single string in a listview?

Comment: An arraylist of strings, so a list of strings. E.g. {"Cow", "Plant", "Tree"}

Comment: I posted my answer what you are expecting you just use it and tell me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this list view for you and you can use this one for a example and use this And if you have any doubts on this listview comment me..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ArrayList<String> mListItems;
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        mListItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String name : mStrings)
        {
            mListItems.add(name);
        }

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mListItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);   


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
                    long i) {
                String name = (String) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
                MainActivity.this.adapter.remove(name);         
            }
        });
    }


    private String[] mStrings = { "Abbaye de Belloc", "Abbaye du Mont des Cats", "Abertam", "Abondance", "Ackawi",
            "Acorn", "Adelost", "Affidelice au Chablis", "Afuega'l Pitu", "Airag", "Airedale", "Aisy Cendre",
            "Allgauer Emmentaler", "Abbaye de Belloc", "Abbaye du Mont des Cats", "Abertam", "Abondance", "Ackawi",
            "Acorn", "Adelost", "Affidelice au Chablis", "Afuega'l Pitu", "Airag", "Airedale", "Aisy Cendre",
            "Allgauer Emmentaler","Abbaye de Belloc", "Abbaye du Mont des Cats", "Abertam", "Abondance", "Ackawi",
            "Acorn", "Adelost", "Affidelice au Chablis", "Afuega'l Pitu", "Airag", "Airedale", "Aisy Cendre",
            "Allgauer Emmentaler", "Abbaye de Belloc", "Abbaye du Mont des Cats", "Abertam", "Abondance", "Ackawi",
            "Acorn", "Adelost", "Affidelice au Chablis", "Afuega'l Pitu", "Airag", "Airedale", "Aisy Cendre",
            "Allgauer Emmentaler" };
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This did exactly what I wanted in a few lines. Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

There is nice "Swipe to dismiss" project on [GitHub: Android-SwipeToDismiss](https://github.com/romannurik/android-swipetodismiss), that you
can use together with the example ListViews included on this thread. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

private ListView lv;

public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

     lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id);

     // Instanciating an array list (you don't need to do this, 
     // you already have yours).
     List<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
     your_array_list.add("foo");
     your_array_list.add("bar");

     // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a 
     // first parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your 
     // array as a third parameter.
     ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
             this, 
             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
             your_array_list );

     lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a ListView with an id `listview` in your `activity_main.xml` the following code should work.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        int rows = 10;

        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i ++) {
            values.add("row " + i);
        }

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

You will have to look into Adapters to get a full understanding of how ListView works. Here is a very good video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA.